# Custom DynamoDBMapper with spring-data-dynamodb

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have a case when I need to use different DynamoDb tables with different environments.
For example, I want to have DevTable on dev and ProdTable on prod.

So, is there any way to use custom DynamoDBMapper with spring-data repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DynamoDBMapperConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.html) provides a way to override the TableName specified on the Entity object using `@DynamoDBTable` annotation, through [`TableNameOverride`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.html) class.

You can define a `TableNameOverride` bean that modifies the table name at runtime, in your spring-data based application. See https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Alter-table-name-during-runtime.